# How to make c3 ignore comma in column-values

Tags: angularjs, c3.js

I'm using c3-angular-directive to draw a chart. In c3, values are read as a string that looks like this:

```
['val1', 'val2','val3']
```

My problem is that I have a comma in some of those values (note the `,` in `val,1`),

```
['val,1', 'val2','val3']
```

and c3 automatically understands this as 4 values instead of 3. Is there a way to pass the values so that it ignores this comma?

Here is my code:

```
<c3chart bindto-id="chart" show-labels="true" ng-if="chartData.show">
    <chart-size chart-height="{{chartData.height}}"/>
    <chart-column column-id="x" column-values="{{chartData.names}}" />
    <chart-column column-id="data1" 
                  column-name="D" 
                  column-values="{{chartData.valuesD}}"
                  column-type="bar" />
    <chart-column column-id="data2" 
                  column-name="Z" 
                  column-values="{{chartData.valuesZ}}"
                  column-type="bar" />
    <chart-bar ratio="0.8" />
    <chart-axes values-x="x" y="data1,data2" />
    <chart-axis axis-rotate="true">
        <chart-axis-x axis-type="category">
            <chart-axis-x-tick tick-centered="true"
                               tick-multiline="false" />
            </chart-axis-x>
        <chart-axis-y axis-id="y" 
                      axis-position="outer-right" 
                      axis-label="Number od D & Z" />
        </chart-axis>
</c3chart>
```

The problem is in

```
<chart-column column-id="x" column-values="{{chartData.names}}" />
```

in chartData.names which can sometimes have commas.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to cleanse your data of commas - try using the html entity number `&#44;` in place of the comma.

```
var namesRaw = ['val,1', 'val2','val3'];
var namesClean = namesRaw.map(function(name) {
    if (typeof name !== 'string') {
        return name;
    } else {
        return name.replace(',', '&#44;');
    }
});
```

I think because of the way the angular uses the DOM, your javascript array of column-values will be flattened to a single string when it finally becomes a DOM attribute.

```
chartData.names = ['val,1', 'val2','val3']
<chart-column column-id="x" column-values="{{chartData.names}}" />
```

I think the column-values becomes `column-values="val,1,val2,val3"` in the DOM at some point.

And then the [code in c3-angular-directive](https://github.com/jettro/c3-angular-directive/blob/master/src/column-directive.js#L48) is just doing `"val,1,val2,val3".split(',')`

Comment: Tried with &#44; - as expected, it doesn't separate the value anymore, but writes out &#44; instead of comma.

Comment: Ok, we need a way to tell angular that its ok to render html... I'm looking at it, but it may require updating the c3-angular-directive code. I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: @ljerka Hey, so it looks like there's not a good way to do it unless we change the c3-angular-directive code and even then the approaches I'm thinking of have problems. Can you substitute any other symbol or punctuation in place of the comma? Like `.` or `;` or `-` ? You could use the same code  `name.replace(',', 'newPunctionation');`

Comment: @ljerka I posted an issue on the github to start a discussion on if/how to fix it. https://github.com/jettro/c3-angular-directive/issues/161

Comment: I already replaced it with a space sign, but would like to "fix it properly" sometime in the future :) Thank you for your effort and for posting an issue.